# how to create service FirebaseMessagingService always active in background

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Hello guys can you help me how to create `FirebaseMessagingService` always active in background if have `push notification` or not and then add times 5 minutes for wake up service and sleep apps

thank you

this one **my code**

```
public class FcmServiceMessage extends FirebaseMessagingService{

String message, title;
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage mMessage) {
    //Bundle extras = data.getExtras();

    Map data =  mMessage.getData();
    //String message = data.get("message").toString();
    if (data.containsKey("message")){
        message = data.get("message").toString();
    }

    if (data.containsKey("title")){
        title = data.get("title").toString();
    }

    showNotification();

}

private void showNotification(){
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,"channel_Id")
            .setOngoing(false)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon_small)
            .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white))
            .setLargeIcon(convertToBitmap(getApplication().getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)))
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setTicker(message)
            .setStyle(bigTextStyle)
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH);

    return builder.build();

    notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel("channel_Id", "MyApps", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
    notificationChannel.setLightColor(R.color.white);
    notificationChannel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
 }
}
```

and then

> implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.1.0'

Comment: The messaging service should be created in the background already. This sounds like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the problem you're having? And what is the [minimal code with which you can recreate it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: can you give me code for example @FrankvanPuffelen because i follow from Firebase tutorial but same on my phone Asus, Sony and then Samsung not have push notification. i think i need the service message for active on background or apps to swap

Comment: That's not how Stack Overflow works. If you're having a hard time making FCM work, share the [minimal code that reproduces where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read the link please, it's quite useful).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen okay i already add my FCM but Push notification is not receiving after an hour. App needs to open again then able to get notification in background but after an hour die again, no push

Answer (score 0):

onMessageReceived() is not called when application is on background. I have this problem few months a ago. I resolve it by override handlerIntent method. But you should downgrade your firebase messaging library to implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.1'

after that:

```
@Override
    public void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
        try
        {
            if (intent.getExtras() != null)
            {
                RemoteMessage.Builder builder = new RemoteMessage.Builder("MessagingService");

                for (String key : intent.getExtras().keySet())
                {
                    builder.addData(key, intent.getExtras().get(key).toString());
                }

                onMessageReceived(builder.build());
            }
            else
            {
                super.handleIntent(intent);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            super.handleIntent(intent);
        }
    }
```

if you don't want to downgrade your library then

You can specify a click_action to indicate the intent that should be launched when the notification is tapped by the user. The main activity is used if no click_action is specified.

When the intent is launched you can use the

```
getIntent().getExtras();
```

to retrieve a Set that would include any data sent along with the notification message.

For more on notification message see https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive#sample-receive

Comment: where i put this one on the MainActivity or on service?

Comment: on your FcmServiceMessage class